# How to initialize an array of dictionaries

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, initialization

I cant seem to get this syntax correct or any resource that has an example of this.

Am trying something like:

```
Row = new Dictionary<string, string> [] [{"A":"A"}, {"B":"B"}]
```

Any idea on this syntax?

Comment: What are you trying to create here? An array with one element?

Comment: @ChaseErnst Very similar but the linked thread doesn't present collection initializers used for the inner dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
Row = new Dictionary<string, string>[] 
{ 
    new Dictionary<string, string> { {"A", "A"} }, 
    new Dictionary<string, string> { {"B", "B"} } 
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for both the array and the inner [dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx):

```
var arrayOfDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, string>[] 
{ 
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"A", "A"} }, 
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"B", "B"} } 
};
```

You can read more about this syntax on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx).